# Edit Example Foo Entity

Tags: jhipster

I have created the basic example foo entity and am now looking to start customizing entities user flow etc.  I added the following two properties to the foo domain in the Foo.Java file

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "client_first_name") 
private String clientFirstName;

@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "client_last_name") 
private String clientLastName;
```

I then modified the liquibase final lines of the db-changelog-001.xml to reflect the changes made to the class

```
<changeSet id="100" author="jhipster"><createTable tableName="T_FOO">
        <column name="id" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="sample_text_attribute" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="sample_date_attribute" type="date"/>
        <column name="client_first_name" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="client_last_name" type="varchar(50)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Are there any good tutorials for entity modification that outline the appropriate way to modify entities with the given tech stack? Or in other words what is the recommended approach for customizing entities when developing with a jHipster scaffolded application?

Answer (score 1):

Work through all the files generated by JHipster that contain property fields, and edit them accordingly - see the files tagged with ** below. Note that some file names will change in JHipster v2. Of course, if you want to upgrade a production environment (i.e. when changing tables in a populated database), you'll have to create a liquibase changelog entry specifically to add/delete/edit the new field/s.

```
** src/main/java/com/someapp/webapp/domain/SomeEntity.java
   src/main/java/com/someapp/webapp/repository/SomeEntityRepository.java
   src/main/java/com/someapp/webapp/web/rest/SomeEntityResource.java
** src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/20141125090927_added_entity_SomeEntity.xml**
** src/main/webapp/views/SomeEntitys.html
   src/main/webapp/scripts/SomeEntity/router_SomeEntity.js
** src/main/webapp/scripts/SomeEntity/controller_SomeEntity.js
   src/main/webapp/scripts/SomeEntity/service_SomeEntity.js
** src/test/java/com/someapp/webapp/web/rest/SomeEntityResourceTest.java
```